# Ducking music using FFmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, artificial-intelligence, signal-processing, audio-processing

I want to duck a music audio with a speech audio using `FFmpeg` (ducking is commonly used to lower background music anytime a person speaks, then raises it when that person finishes speaking). How can I do it with `FFmpeg` or any other tools (if any)?

There was an FFmpeg filter called `sidechaincompress` which merges the two, but it doesn't "duck" them. It takes 2 audio inputs, 1st input to be compressed depending on the signal of 2nd input and later compressed signal to be merged with 2nd input:

```
ffmpeg -i main.flac -i sidechain.flac -filter_complex "[1:a]asplit=2[sc][mix];[0:a][sc]sidechaincompress[compr];[compr][mix]amerge"
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `amix` not `amerge`. `amerge` for example combines 2 2-channel audios to 4-channel audio IIRC. `amix` combines signals on each channel.

Comment: Idk. One thing is also use of a param called `threshold`.